How to import a file to MongoDB with escaped unicode sequences?
I'm working in R with a dataframe containing a column with escaped unicode sequences:
d <- data.frame(id = 1, norm = "m\u0350pini\u0306\u030Ds\u0313u")

I ultimately need to import the dataframe into MongoDB (I'm using Compass) so that the corresponding unicode characters are correctly displayed. I tried saving it to a simple tab delimited text file, but MongoDB treats the unicode column as a string; so I tried saving it as a json:
library(jsonlite)

j <- tojson(d,dataframe="rows",pretty=T)

write(j,"jstest.json")

However, this automatically adds another backslash to the escaped sequences, giving m\\u0350pini\\u0306\\u030Ds\\u0313u, which again MongoDB does not interpret as unicode.If I insert a document into MongoDB manually which single backslashes, the unicode symbols appear, but this is very impractical for me (thousands of documents).What am I doing wrong?Thanks for the help.
I tried using mongoimport:
d <- data.frame(id=c(1,2),unicode=c("m\u0350pini\u030Ds\u03131u","a\u0350mpi\u030D\u03B7"))
js <- toJSON(d,dataframe = "rows",pretty = T)
write(js,"jstest.json")

mongoimport -d test -c newcoll --type json --file jtest.json --jsonArray

However, the documents still don't display the characters:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("666b08603505c9daeb20edc7"), "id" : 1, "unicode" : "m\\u0350pini\\u030Ds\\u03131u" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("666b08603505c9daeb20edc8"), "id" : 2, "unicode" : "a\\u0350mpi\\u030D\\u03B7" }

The only way I can get the result I want, which is exactly like @Konrad Rudolph 's second comment, is if I manually insert a document with single slashes.

“but MongoDB treats the unicode column as a string” —  What do you mean by that? Of course it’s a string. Anyway, how are you importing the data into MongoDB?

I fundamentally can’t reproduce your problem. I’m not using Compass, but when saving the data as a TSV (I use ‘readr’ but it doesn’t really matter) and importing it via mongoimport, the resulting document in MongoDB looks exactly as expected ({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "666abfb67631abad9783bf8f" }, "id" : 1, "norm" : "m͐pinĭ̍s̓u" }).

Sorry, I was unclear, what I mean is that the unicode sequences are interpreted literally, without being converted to the correct character. I am using the Add Data functionality in Compass. What I don't understand is why, when I import a json, strings like m\\u0350pini\\u0306\\u030Ds\\u0313u are interpreted literally, but replacing \ with \ results in an error because of "escaped characters".

This is still not clear: what do you mean by “literally” and by “correct character”? Is the result I’ve shown in my previous comment what you expect? If so, the issue seems to be with the Compass import functionality, not with R (nor with MongoDB). Try using mongoimport.

@KonradRudolph I followed the instructions in your second comment and succeeded, thank tou! Repost as an answer, if you will, i'll gladly upvote it.


Inside R, export the data to TSV (e.g. via ‘readr’):
readr::write_tsv(d, 'd.tsv')


Use mongoimport to import the data:
mongoimport --db mydb --collection mycollection --type tsv --file d.tsv --headerline



